# ESLint and TypeScript Setup Issues

Tags: typescript, eslint, lint

I'm new to eslint so I'm trying to set up a typescript project to use the default configuration but I'm getting errors in my ts files I can't figure out how to fix for example `import { type Response, type Request } from 'express';` in this line is asking me to remove the semicolon and I do not want that, also in the code below wants to remove the tab to a single space

```
getAllProperties(request: Request, response: Response): void {

        const properties = this.proteryService.getAllProperties();
        response.json(properties);

    }
```

this is the command line that I ran so far

```
sudo npm install -g eslint
npx eslint --init
```

During the setup I picked the most standard options, below is my config file

```
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es2021": true
    },
    "extends": "standard-with-typescript",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": "latest",
        "sourceType": "commonjs"
    },
    "rules": {  
    }
}
```

I try to override the rules with no luck